# Can a multipart 7bit MIME message contain submessages of type 8bit or binary?

Tags: mime

I am new to MIME, and I don't know if the following situation is valid:

Consider two nested MIME messages: the top-level message has Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The body of the top-level message is a nested MIME message that has Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary. The body of the internal message has lines that end in LF only, rather than CRLF.

I think this message is invalid, because the rules for 7bit say that LF by itself is not valid. However, a colleague is arguing that this message is valid, because the Content-Transfer-Encoding of the inner message is binary, which doesn't have any restrictions around CR LF.

My argument is that the entire body of the top-level message needs to conform to its encoding (7bit), regardless of the Content-Transfer-Encoding of any nested messages.

I've searched the web and tried to find the answer in the MIME spec, but was not able to find anything that seemed to address this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in section 6.4 of RFC 2045:

> It should also be noted that, by definition, if a composite entity has
>   a transfer-encoding value such as "7bit", but one of the enclosed
>   entities has a less restrictive value such as "8bit", then either the
>   outer "7bit" labelling is in error, because 8bit data are included, or
>   the inner "8bit" labelling placed an unnecessarily high demand on the
>   transport system because the actual included data were actually
>   7bit-safe.

So the message in my example is invalid.

Comment: Frequently, though, multiparts don't specify an encoding at all; it is specified separately in the headers of each contained part.